# Can QGIS produce Stage Storage Plan?

Tags: qgis, elevation, basin

I work for an engineering firm.

Can QGIS produce a stage storage plan for multiple drainage basins?

I am attaching an image of what I am talking about.

Currently, we use a combination of Autodesk products to get this map created.  It consists of 3 separate sub-basins with 3 separate elevation tables. However, due to the size of the LiDAR data that we have, along with the large areas that we are working with, it is taking far too long as the software takes a while to regenerate the data.  The president of the company asked me to look at ArcGIS to see if this would be a better solution, and I have dabbled in QGIS to do some other GIS related workflows with it, and I would rather use it to produce the plans, as it is not only free, but seems like it has any plugin imaginable.

[image: Stage Storage Plan]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, QGIS can produce a map that looks like the one you included, as well as the data tables on the side. It should be quite a simple task:

1. Overlay elevation layers on top of a satellite image
2. Set up the symbology and labels
3. Add attribute tables, a legend, north arrow and scale bar in the print composer

The only challenge would be getting the colors into the tables, as the legend is a separate item from an attribute table. There are a few ways to work around that, however.